# Linux Shell scripting: Storing the output of a command line program

Tags: linux, bash, shell, acpi

The following command returns 2 lines and those are the temperatures of my CPU's:

```
acpi -t
```

How would I go about storing those 2 lines in a variable in a bash script so I can work with them?

Answer (score 1):

Did u try this ?

`var=$(acpi -t)`

Comment: yep that does not work. returns: ./temp.sh: line 2: =Thermal: command not found

Comment: Use the full path to `acpi`, e.g. `/usr/bin/acpi`.

Comment: make sure you don't leave space after `=` for eg: `var= $(acpi -t)`